# Nothing is being echoed when using mysqli_num_rows()

Tags: php, mysqli

I am sorry if this is a noob question, but I've been searching all over the internet for an answer and could find nothing that could solve my issue. Anyways, I've taken a look at the php documentation on mysqli_num_rows() (which is https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) since I am trying to find the amount of rows in a column. My table looks like this:

```
id | follower  |  followee
1    Xp10d3       IiBlurBeriI
2    IiBlurBeriI  Xp10d3
```

In id number 1, the table shows that IiBlurBeriI has a follower of Xp10d3, and in id number 2 the table shows that Xp10d3 has a follower of IiBlurBeriI. I am trying to get all the subscribers where the username is equal to the profile that is being viewed. Anyways, I used the mysqli_num_rows() method to try and execute this but obviously it doesn't work. I don't get any MySQL errors whatsoever, but when viewing the amount of followers it is blank like this:

```
Username
 followers.
 following.
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
Username
5 followers.
2 following.
```

The rest of the MySQL that I used to view the profile worked fine; it was just the follower/following system that I had an issue with. My code is below:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $servername = "localhost"; // Host name 
    $user = "xxxx"; // Mysql username 
    $pass = "xxxx"; // Mysql password 
    $dbname = "xxxx"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name = "forum_question"; // Table name 

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $pass, $dbname);
    $userGet = $_GET['username'];
    $userGetSQL = "SELECT USERNAME FROM data WHERE USERNAME='".$userGet."'";
    $result = $conn->query($userGetSQL);
    $userRow = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $pfp = "SELECT PFP FROM data WHERE USERNAME = '".$_GET['username']."'";
    $pfpresult = $conn->query($pfp);
    $pfprow = $pfpresult->fetch_assoc();

    $rank = "SELECT LEVEL FROM data WHERE USERNAME = '".$_GET['username']."'";
    $rresult = $conn->query($rank);

    $followers = "SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE follower = '".$_GET['username']."'";
    $fresult = $conn->query($followers);
    $fcnt = $fresult->num_rows;

    //echo "FOR TESTING PURPOSES! Followers query: " . $followers . ". Result: " . $fresult . ". num_rows: " . $fcnt . ".";

    $following = "SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE followee = '".$_GET['username']."'";
    $ffresult = $conn->query($following);
    $ffcnt = $ffresult->num_rows;

    //echo "FOR TESTING PURPOSES! Following query: " . $following . ". Result: " . $ffresult . ". num_rows: " . $ffcnt. ".";

    $desc = "SELECT DESCRIPTON FROM data WHERE USERNAME = '".$_GET['username']."'";
    $descresult = $conn->query($desc);
    $descRow = $descresult->fetch_assoc();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) && empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
        echo 'You are not logged in! Go <a href="main_forum.php">home</a> to login!';
    } else {
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        .card {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            max-width: 300px;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .title {
            color: grey;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        .msg{
            border: none;
            outline: 0;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 8px;
            color: white;
            background-color: #000;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 22px;
            color: black;
        }

        .msg:hover, a:hover {
            opacity: 0.7;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" style="cursor:pointer">
        <a href="main_forum.php">Home</a>
    </button>
    <br />
    <?php
        $check = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE follower = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND followee = '".$_GET['username']."'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0) {
    ?>
            <button type="button" style="cursor:pointer">
                <a href='unfollow.php?username=<?php echo $userGet ?>'>Unfollow</a>
            </button>
    <?php
        } else {
    ?>
            <button type="button" style="cursor:pointer">
                <a href='follow.php?username=<?php echo $userGet ?>'>Follow</a>
            </button>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    <div class="card">
        <?php
            if ($pfprow['PFP'] == none.png) {
        ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $pfprow['PFP'] ?>" id="pfp" style="width:100%" />
        <?php
        } else {
        ?>
            <img src="pfp/<?php echo $pfprow['PFP'] ?>" id="pfp" style="width:100%" />
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <h1 id="username"><?php echo $_GET['username'] ?></h2>
        <p id="title"><?php echo $rrow['LEVEL'] ?></p>
        <p><strong><?php echo $fcount ?></strong> followers.</p>
        <p><strong><?php echo $ffcount ?></strong> following.</p>
        <div class="desc">
            <?php
                echo $descRow['DESCRIPTON'];
            ?>
        </div>
        <p><button class="msg"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Send Message</button></p>    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    }
    exit();
?>
```

On a side note, yes I know my code is vulnerable to SQL injection. I am trying to learn how to use prepared statements (I am a new to PHP but have used HTML+CSS for a couple of years) so that I can change my code later on. I don't believe I have any INSERT statements so this should be fine.

Comment: In your PHP code, you use `fcnt` and `ffcnt` to store the number of rows, but in the HTML table, you use `fcount` and `ffcount`, which are undefined variables.

Comment: You also are open to SQL injections. Parameterize and used prepared statements.

Comment: You should also just be selecting `count(*)` if the only thing you need is the count. SQL injection also has nothing to do with the type of statement you intend to execute.

Comment: @JoffreySchmitz whoops; didn't catch that :/ Thanks!
user3783243 and Dharman yes, I am quite new to PHP and am trying to learn how to use prepared statements. I am aware of the risks. And I forgot about COUNT; sorry about that. Should've looked into it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Setting aside the SQL injection vulnerabilities that you already mentioned, if you want to know how many rows have, for example, `follower = 'some_follower'`, do a COUNT instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM subscribers WHERE follower = 'some_follower'
```

Because if you do a `SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE follower = 'some_follower'` you are asking the DB to return all the results, while you just want to know the COUNT.

Example in PHP:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM subscribers WHERE follower = 'some_follower'");
$row = $result->fetch_row();

echo '#: ', $row[0];
```